# Obtener el alumno con mayor promedio por carrera SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Debo obtener el alumno con mayor promedio por carrera, tengo sólo 3 alumnos
[image: Alumnos]

Sólo debe salir Claudia y Pedro, esto es lo que llevo.

```
select carrera as 'Carrera', max(prom) as 'Promedio'
from (Select c.nombre as carrera, a.nombre as nombre,avg(h.calificacion) as prom
from horario h
join alumno a on (h.clave_alumno = a.clave)
join materia m on (m.clave = h.clave_materia)
join carrera c on (a.clave_carrera =c.clave)
group by a.nombre, c.nombre) as promedio 
group by carrera
```

[image: Promedios más altos]

Si quiero el nombre con ese query, me vuelven a salir los tres alumnos

[image: lo que no quiero]

Si alguien puede ayudarme, se lo agradecería mucho :c

No debo usar limit o top, debe ser por una consulta correlacionada

[image: diagrama]
[image: tablas]

Comment: Podrías mostrar la estructura(columnas) de cada tabla por favor?

Comment: @BetaM actualicé el post:)

Comment: Por simplificar creo que la tabla materia aquí es irrelevante.

Comment: Si alguien se anima, he creado un fiddle pero aun no doy con la consulta: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9keUYXYj76TikMQhJ3qWvW/2

Answer (score 4):

Si lo soporta tu versión de SQL Server puedes usar dos técnicas muy prácticas:

- Una [common table expresion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para generar una subconsulta temporal al vuelo
- [`row_number()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para numerar cada fila, de forma tal que el 1 siempre corresponda a la calificación más alta por materia.

SQL:

```
;with cte as (
select c.nombre as carrera,
       a.nombre,
       a.apellido,
       h.promedio,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c.nombre order by h.promedio desc, a.clave) as rn
       from (select c.clave as clave_carrera,
                    a.clave as clave_alumno,
                    avg(calificacion) as promedio
                    from horario h
                    inner join alumno a
                        on a.clave = h.clave_alumno
                    inner join carrera c
                        on c.clave = a.clave_carrera
                    group by 
                        c.clave,
                            a.clave
            ) h
       inner join alumno a 
           on a.clave = h.clave_alumno
       inner join carrera c
           on c.clave = h.clave_carrera
)
select carrera,
       nombre,
       apellido,
       promedio
       from cte
       where rn = 1
```

Este código te retornará el alumno con la calificación más alta por carrera, hay que tener en cuenta que en este caso, si hay dos con la misma calificación, solo retornará uno de ellos.

Un enfoque más tradicional y ANSI SQL sería usar varias subconsultas anidadas, necesitamos básicamente, conocer:

1. Los promedios por alumno/arrera
2. El promedio máximo por carrera

Algo así:

```
select  mm.nombre,
        aa.nombre,
        aa.apellido,
        aa.promedio
        from ( -- Alumnos/carreras y sus promedios
              select c.clave as clave_carrera,
                     c.nombre as carrera_nombre,
                     a.nombre,
                     a.apellido,
                     avg(h1.calificacion) as promedio
                     from horario h1
                     inner join alumno a
                         on h1.clave_alumno = a.clave
                     inner join carrera c
                        on c.clave = a.clave_carrera
                     group by 
                         c.clave,
                         c.nombre,
                         a.nombre,
                         a.apellido
             
           ) aa
      inner join (
          -- máximos promedios por carrera
          select clave,
                 max(promedio) as promedio_max
                 from (
                     select c.clave,
                            a.nombre,
                            a.apellido,
                            avg(h1.calificacion) as promedio
                            from horario h1
                            inner join alumno a
                                on h1.clave_alumno = a.clave
                            inner join carrera c
                               on c.clave = a.clave_carrera
                            group by 
                                c.clave,
                                a.nombre,
                                a.apellido
                    ) cm
                    group by clave_carrera      
       
            ) cc
            on cc.clave = aa.clave_carrera
            and cc.promedio_max = aa.promedio
```

Comment: ¿Se puede hacer sin funciones de ventana, al estilo "tradicional"? En realidad la solución es parecida a usar un TOP.

Comment: Justo estaba armando el código para una versión más ANSI SQL, se puede pero es bastante más larga

Comment: Sí, lo imagino. No dejes de compartirla.

Comment: @AntonioSánchez, revisa mi última edición, agregue el enfoque tradicional. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho muchas gracias, me sirvió bastante:)

Comment: @PatricioMoracho La consulta con ventana no da el resultado esperado, es decir Claudia y Pedro con sus correspondientes promedios. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9keUYXYj76TikMQhJ3qWvW/4

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Y la Ansi Sql tampoco. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9keUYXYj76TikMQhJ3qWvW/5

Comment: @ChoiFernanda66 ¿Lo has resuelto? ¿Puedes compartir la solución? Como comento a mi no me sale con las consultas de Patricio.

Comment: @AntonioSánchez, es cierto, olvide que el promedio es por carrera me quede en la materia. Agrego la tabla. Gracias!

Comment: De hecho la materia es prescindible por completo en la consulta.

Comment: @AntonioSánchez, si efectivamente la materia es prescindible de la consulta

Comment: @AntonioSánchez Si, utilicé el código ANSI y lo modifiqué por carrera como ya está corregido ahora :)